# @@error returns 0 although the condition is not satisfied

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
raiserror('Hello world', 16, 1) 
if (@@error > 0)
    print @@error
```

Why does it even return 0? If shouldn't allow to do so.

Comment: Even the `if` statement causes `@@error` to be set. and the `if` statement itself runs successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@@Error stores the error for only a single call on the immediate line after the error.
See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx
Try this

```
declare @x int
raiserror('Hello world', 16, 1) 
set @x=@@error 
if (@x > 0)
   print @x
```